# SoftLayer Python Client API - create an instance on Public VLAN

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to specify both frontend and beckend VLAN ids but there is only one attribute for public_vlan in the create_instance function. 
How do I specify both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify public and private vlans, public is for frontend and privated for backend:

see documentation about the method:
https://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/managers/vs/#SoftLayer.managers.vs.VSManager.create_instance

Regards